# Foundation sticky menu links won't work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, zurb-foundation

In my site, I used Foundation's Magellan sticky menu in the bottom. When I open the site in Firefox the menu works. But when I open it in Google Chrome the links are not working (Even the cursor pointer won't appear when hovered over the text. That means the links are missing). Why is it happening?

You can see the problem in here : http://leafycode.com/

Comment: Your `#container` div is sitting over the bottom navigation, if you add `position:relative` to `#serviceNav` then the bottom nav will be above the `#container`, and therefore should now be clickable.

Comment: @NickR Thanks a lot! It worked! Can you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#container` div is sitting over the bottom navigation, if you add `position:relative` to `#serviceNav` then the bottom nav will be above the `#container`, and therefore should now be clickable.